Site is still "read-only" for me
The main site philosophy.stackexchange.com is still read-only for me in Firefox after the outage ~4 hours ago, although I can see others are now able to use it normally and I can use it normally in Chromium. Maybe a problem in DNS propagation, am I pointed at the wrong server? Firefox takes me to 104.18.43.226:443 while Chromium sends me to 172.64.144.30:443.
Maybe 104.18.43.226 was left in read-only mode by accident?

Well, it wasn't the server, it was something on my computer. Clearing the browser history fixed it. (Note that you can clear browser history for one specific site by going to History -> Manage History -> right click on philosophy.stackexchange.com -> Forget about this site) Firefox is still going to 104.18.43.226 but it is working now.

Management of caching is one of the fundamental problems of computer science!
